# How to separate month's worth of timestamped data by day

Tags: bash, datetime, unix

I have a .log file which restarts at the beginning of each month, each message beginning with the following timestamp format: `01-07-2016 00:00:00:868|`

There are thousands of messages per day and I'd like to create a short script which can figure out when the date increments and output each date to a new file with just that day's data.  I'm not proficient in bash but I'd like to use sed or awk, as it's very useful for automating processes at my job and creating reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below script will split the input log file into multiple files with the date added as a suffix to the input file name:

**split_logfile_by_date**

```
#!/bin/bash

exec < $1
while read line
do
    date=$(echo $line|cut -d" " -f 1)
    echo $line >> $1.$date
done
```

**Example:**

```
$ ls
log
$ split_logfile_by_date log
$ ls
log  log.01-07-2016  log.02-07-2016  log.03-07-2016
```

Comment: When you use a while-loop, try minimalising the operations inside the loop. You could use `while read -r logdate; do grep "${logdate}"  logfile > "outfile.${logdate}"; done < <(cut -d" " -f1 logfile | sort -u) `.

Comment: @WalterA What you propose came to my mind first, but I decided to scan the file only once. Then, if needed the script can be used with streaming data, too.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for your assistance my friend!  I don't really need to stream data but it's nice to have the option.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{log = FILENAME "." $1; print > log}' logfile
```

This will write all the `01-07-2016` records to the file `logfile.01-07-2016`

Comment: BTW, terrible datetime format. use [YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm) to be unambiguous

Comment: Use something like `mylog`, not `log` (logarithm).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working in an enterprise environment and the datetime  formatting is not exactly my choice ;-) @glennjackman